# vimscript - catching keystrokes with autocommands

Tags: vim, keystroke

Say, if I need to process an `:ex` command I can use `getcmdline()` tied with `CmdWinLeave`, for example. This way I can, for example, automatically catch when a window is closed.

But I cannot catch, for example, a `:h CTRL-W_q` in that way.

I would like to know **how could I catch this kind of keystrokes being pressed** (not necessarily in relation to windows). Thank you!

Comment: Did you consider mapping those commands to something custom?

Comment: Hey, hello again) This would lead to remapping of a lot of mappings, plus the other users could have their own, so that is not an option, unfortunately.